# Jboss 6.4 encrypted password not working

Tags: java, linux, jboss, jboss6.x

I am trying to enable the jboss password encryption on jboss 6.4 version I have tried all the options mentioned in different forums and getting access denied always. Below is the change I have tried out. In the domain.xml added a security domain. Any help is highly appreciated. I am seeing the user of oracle getting locked, so it is taking the right user but giving a wrong password.

```
 <security-domain name="security-ds" cache-type="default">
 <authentication>
     <login-module code="org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule" flag="required">
        <module-option name="username" value="username"/>
            <module-option name="password" value="-encryptedhash"/>
            <module-option name="managedConnectionFactoryName" value="jboss.jca:service=LocalTxCM,name=myds"/>
    </login-module>
 </authentication>
 </security-domain>
```

And in the data source added the security domain.

```
               <datasource jndi-name="java:/myds" pool-name="myds" enabled="true" use-java-context="false">
                    <connection-url>${url}</connection-url>
                    <connection-property name="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout">
                       72000
                    </connection-property>
                    <driver>oracle</driver>
                    <pool>
                        <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
                        <max-pool-size>5</max-pool-size>
                        <flush-strategy>FailingConnectionOnly</flush-strategy>
                    </pool>
                    <security-domain>security-ds</security-domain>
                     <validation>
                        <check-valid-connection-sql>select 1 from dual</check-valid-connection-sql>
                        <validate-on-match>true</validate-on-match>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
```

Generating hash password

```
java org.picketbox.datasource.security.SecureIdentityLoginModule <password>
```

Comment: Just use the vault extension provided by JBOSS https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecuringPasswords

Answer (score 0):

I do recommend using the JBoss Password Vault vice the SecureIdentityLoginModule, as the SecureIdentityLoginModule uses a hard-coded encryption/decryption key "jaas is the way". At the very least, if you choose to go this route, you should create your own package that implements the SecureIdentityLoginModule with a different key.
All that said, your problem could be as simple as not enclosing your password argument in quotes, especially if the password contains certain special characters.